# Kendo MVVM binding on null values binds as object

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, kendo-ui

there seems to be a rather peculiar design decision when it comes to the binding behaviour in Kendo.

I'm trying to bind a nullable value to a drop down list. If the (remotely sourced) value is null, then Kendo will generate objects to bind to the value instead, for example, using the data-value-field/value of the dropdown.
This makes saving the modified viewmodel extremely unreliable, since now entire objects would get transmitted instead of simple data types.

Example:
`Schedule.WeekNumber` is `null`. After selecting a value from a DropDown like

```
<select data-role="dropdownlist" name="scheduleWeekOfMonth"
    data-bind="value:WeekNumber">
  <option value="">Every week</option>
  <option value="0">First week of month (1.-7.)</option>
  <option value="1">Second week of month (8.-14.)</option>
  <option value="2">Third week of month (15.-21.)</option>
  <option value="3">Last week of month (22.+)</option>
</select>
```

The value (JSON) then is `Object {text: "First week of month (1.-7.)", value: "0"}` instead of `"0"`

Has anyone got a good solution for this? - besides replacing all null values of the viewmodel on load, eg:

```
function deNull(obj) {
  if(obj !== null && typeof obj === "object") {
    $.each(obj, function(index, value) {
      if(value !== null && typeof value === "object") {
        deNull(obj[index]); // we must go deeper (BRRRRRRRAAAAAWWWWRWRRRMRMRMMRMRMMMMM)
      }
      if(value === null) {
        obj[index] = "";  // workaround, this is the "null" equivalent of not being set         
        //console.log("De-nulled: " + index);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a data-value-primitive attribute you can use to achieve straightforward value binding.

```
<select data-role="dropdownlist" name="scheduleWeekOfMonth"
  data-bind="value:WeekNumber" data-value-primitive="true">
    <option value="">Every week</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Here is a link to [in the docs](https://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/value#use-the-value-binding-with-a-select-widget-to-update-the-view-model-field-with-the-value-field-when-the-initial-value-is-null.) about this attribute. Also, there is a [UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/3356384-dropdown-null-values).

Comment: I believe this attribute was added in the Q2 2013 release of Kendo UI.

Comment: Following up a few months later, I initialize most dropdownlists this way:
$("#typeID").attr('data-value-primitive', 'true').kendoDropDownList();

Comment: The valuePrimitive property is documented here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete#configuration-valuePrimitive

Comment: For the MVC wrapper, add .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" })

Answer (score 0):

Question was discussed multiple times. Either set default value so the value is not null when it is bound or check the [following](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/binding-nullable-field-to-dropdownlist-editor-in-grid.aspx) article how to create custom binder.